# Timer is not working in GWT,

Tags: gwt, timer

I am redirecting some other web page when execution finishes on my side. I want to display message to my user that we are "redirecting in %d seconds" for that I used Timer class,but it is still redirecting instantly.

Code is below.

```
 public void redirect(){
      hanldeWait() ;
       Window.Location.assign(Url) ;
 }

   private void hanldeWait(){
    Timer timer = new Timer() {
        int i = 5 ;
        public void run() {
            if(i < 0){
                errorMessage.setVisible(false);
                cancel() ;
            }else{
                i-- ;
                String redirectionMessage = "Redirecting in %d seconds" ;
                String displayMessage = redirectionMessage ;

                displayMessage  = format(redirectionMessage, (Integer)i) ;
                errorMessage.setText(displayMessage);
                errorMessage.setVisible(true);

            }
        }
      };
      timer.scheduleRepeating(5000) ;
}
```

If i am doing something wrong here.

Comment: `scheduleRepeating(5000)` should be `schedule(5000)` if you only want it to run once.

Comment: no, i want to repeat until i reaches to 0.

Comment: But you already tell it to run again by `this.schedule(1000)`. This line cancels `scheduleRepeating(5000)`.

Comment: thanks Andrei,corrected the code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tells the browser to redirect immediately, with no delay.

If you want to redirect after a delay, then

```
Window.Location.assign(Url) ;
```

should be called *inside* the `run` method of a Timer.